# Autofill Broken for Credit Card Expiration Date

Tags: html, forms, autocomplete, credit-card

For a credit card expiration date, which form elements are “correct” and play nicely with browser autofill?

[image: Broken credit card form empty]
[image: Broken credit card form filled]

I’ve seen two main ways of doing it. As a Safari user, this is the most common field that silently fails when I’m auto-filling payment information. Here’s a failure from a [real-life experience](https://new.cindygordon.com/dfwwest):

##### `<select>`-based field

```
<label for="billing-cc-exp" class="inputLabelPayment">Expiration Date:</label>
<select name="billing-cc-exp" id="billing-cc-exp" onfocus="methodSelect('pmt-gps')" autocomplete="off">
  <option value="0322" selected="selected">03/2022</option>
  <option value="0422">04/2022</option>
  <option value="0522">05/2022</option>
  <option value="0622">06/2022</option>
    …
</select>
```

##### `<input>`-based field

```
<label for="frmCCExp">Expiry</label>
<input name="cc-exp" id="frmCCExp" required placeholder="MM-YYYY" autocomplete="cc-exp">
```

`<input>` is more frequently recommended ([StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25703743/how-to-style-a-credit-card-expiration-date-input-field-to-include-spaces-and-for?rq=1) and [tutorial](https://cloudfour.com/thinks/autofill-what-web-devs-should-know-but-dont/) examples), but I’m not sure if `<select>` [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17017136/how-to-format-credit-card-input-fields-and-expiry-date) example) is specifically a problem, or if it’s just more frequently implemented wrong.  So what about the above `<select>` example breaks autofill, and how would you fix it?

##### Update: `autocomplete` isn't the problem

I’ve tested `autocomplete="cc-exp”`, and the form is still broken for Safari AutoFill, so my self-answer answer is **wrong** (or at least insufficient).

```
<select name="billing-cc-exp" id="billing-cc-exp" onfocus="methodSelect('pmt-gps')" autocomplete="cc-exp">
  <option value="0322" selected="selected">03/2022</option>
  <option value="0422">04/2022</option>
 …
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [HTML autocomplete attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete) on each of those form fields!
The form elements are not the problem here.

Your broken example has `autocomplete=off`, as dumb as that is for an expiration date field. The (presumably) working examples have some combination of `autocomplete=cc-exp` or `cc-exp-month` and `cc-exp-year`.

Fixed webform:

```
<label for="billing-cc-exp" class="inputLabelPayment">Expiration Date:</label>
<select name="billing-cc-exp" id="billing-cc-exp" onfocus="methodSelect('pmt-gps')" autocomplete="cc-exp">
  <option value="03/2022" selected="selected">03/2022</option>
  <option value="04/2022">04/2022</option>
  <option value="05/2022">05/2022</option>
  <option value="06/2022">06/2022</option>
    …
</select>
```

There's nothing special about Safari going on here. Chrome looks to the same attribute ([related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52096767/chrome-credit-card-expiration-autofill-format)). Autofill can work without the attribute, as in this [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/JonathanN/j054kbgx/), but `autocomplete=off` *will* break it!

Comment: This answer is insufficient (see update on Question).

Comment: iOS Safari has its own quirks. It doesn't consider autocomplete to autofill one's credit card. Instead it relies on the input id and name attributes and the label text, for real, as an heuristic. You need to make sure that the word "card" prefix is part of at least the "id" attribute, without the word "credit" on it. Worked for me @Merchako